# PHP удаление и сохранение SimpleXMLElement();

Tags: php, xml

Коллеги есть вопрос, нужно спарсирить xml и удалить из него некоторые продукты.
Название продукта может быть "Лыжи такие-то" 'Велосиипед такойто', ' Тумбочка классная', 'Опасная перчатка'
Соответсвенно есть уже готовый фид, в котором есть эти товары. Задача удалить их по названию. И вот тут проблемка. SimpleXMLElement(); то хочет удалять то не хочет. Даже если условия цикла говорят ему удали этот элемент. Сооружаю новый фид, и как бы некоторые предметы он удалил некоторе нет.
Вот код.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("marketOld.xml"));
$xmlGood = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("marketOld.xml"));
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml), true);
$array = array($xml->getName() => $array);
$response =  new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents("marketOld.xml"));





//Не люблю циклы whale и по этому как бы читаю тот же фаил повторно, но
//но второе чтение нужно для создание итератора
// То есть как в response (Классе 12.000 + продуктов так и в array 12.000)
// Пробовал форичём продёрнуть список записей хмл не вышло, так что пришлось мутить такой костыль
$arrName = array();
for($i = 0; !($i > count($response->shop->offers->offer)); $i++){
    if(isset($response->shop->offers->offer[$i]->name)){
    $arrName[] = (string)$response->shop->offers->offer[$i]->name;
    $stringNameProduct = (string)$response->shop->offers->offer[$i]->name;
    $baneOneName = "Лыжи";
    $pos=mb_strripos($stringNameProduct, $baneOneName);
        if($pos == 0 or $pos > 0){
            unset($response->shop->offers->offer[$i]);
        }
    $baneOneName = "лыжи";
        $pos=mb_strripos($stringNameProduct, $baneOneName);
        if($pos == 0 or $pos > 0){
            unset($response->shop->offers->offer[$i]);
        }
    // В силу того что даже просто Лыжи не удаляет решил стать чуть конкретнее
    $baneOneName = "Беговые лыжи";
    $pos=mb_strripos($stringNameProduct, $baneOneName);
    if($pos == 0 or $pos > 0){
        unset($response->shop->offers->offer[$i]);
    }
    $baneOneName = "Коньковые лыжи";
        $pos=mb_strripos($stringNameProduct, $baneOneName);
        if($pos == 0 or $pos > 0) {
            unset($response->shop->offers->offer[$i]);
        }


    }
}
$response->asXML("VeryNewMarket.xml");
```

Вот чую что что-то недопонимаю, если знаете в чём ошибка подскажите пожалуйста. Как правильно удалить элемент, и как Новый образ записать именно новый документ после удаления

Comment: Забыл добавить, некакими готовыми билиотеками которые инсталються из композера пользоваться нельзя. Проэкт дышит на ладом, так что старший запрещает только классами и методами который имеет сам PHP

Comment: `for($i = 0; !($i > count($response->shop->offers->offer)); $i++){` — судя по всему, цикл будет идти до `$i = len($response->shop->offers->offer)`, т.е. последним значением итератора будет длина массива. Однако допустимые индексы массива — от 0 до длины массива **не включая**

Comment: И ещё один момент: Вы выводили значения `$strungNameProduct` в консоль? Может быть, в переменную вообще не выводятся названия элементов массива?

Comment: Нет нет что Вы это что-то вроде пакета для проверки, куда можно положить перменную задоного типа, и уже её сравнивать. mb_strripos($stringNameProduct, $baneOneName); То есть почему-то хмл говорил мне что имя продукта это класс а не стринг, пришлось такое мутить

Comment: Это очень просто через XSLT. Вы можете попытаться убедить своего менеджера.

Answer (score 0):

я прошу прощения, что в виде ответа. Не могу добавить комментарий.

конструкция вида $response->shop->offers возвращает итерируемый объект, элемент класса SimpleXMLElement. Поэтому делать вот так (string)$response->shop->offers->offer[$i]->name не есть правильно, хотя в частном случае будет работать. У SimpleXMLElement есть метод getName, лучше воспользоваться им.

Всю конструкцию по проверке я бы заменил на preg_match
Конкретно с лыжами if (preg_match('/лыжи/iu', $stringNameProduct))

А можно кусок xml?

Answer (score 0):

Вы не пытались код более компактно писать, избегая этих длииинныыыых наименований и повторного кода? Возможно, регулярки внедрить

```
$offers = &$response->shop->offers->offer;
$exclude = ["Лыжи", "яблоки"];    
$pattern = implode("|", $filter);

foreach($offers as $idx => &$offer){
    $name = (string) $offer->name ?? null;
    if(!$name) continue;
    
    if(preg_match("/$pattern/iu", $name)){
        unset($offer[$idx]);
    }
}
```

как-то так может быть?